# Where can I find WseWsdl3.exe?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, proxy

I am trying to create proxy class from a WSDL. I got the tool name from MSDN website with the link [WseWsdl3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529578.aspx) . But I am not able to find it in my machine. Could anyone please help me to find it out?

Or do i need to install something?

Comment: That is an obsolete tool for the obsolete WSE web service techology. The modern tool you're looking for is svcutil.exe.

Comment: @JohnSaunders My Project is bit old one and with that svcutil.exe, will I be able to produce proxy class?

Comment: Yes, you will. In fact, WSE is more than "a bit old". You should not use it unless you have no choice at all. It is almost unsupported, and may already be unsupported.